# Put processes in efficient mode

Tags: python

Every day I use the efficient mode function to put processes of a certain application in this mode to save cpu usage, but I wanted to automate this with Python so I would like Python to find the processes and put them in efficient mode

I couldn't try anything because I didn't find any article that talked about how to put processes in efficient mode

Comment: Are you looking to run a process with nice from python or create a python script to renice a running program by pid? or are you looking to find processes by some criteria and renice them not knowing their pid